# How to return only one level of keys using Boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have an s3 bucket with a structure like so:

```
bucket
---key_1
   ---sub_key_1
      ---file_a
   ---sub_key_2
      ---file_b
   ---sub_key_3
      ---file_c
```

Where the keys are all separated by /. I want to run a boto 3 command to return just the sub keys. I've tried a few things. Using both the client and session methods of boto 3 mainly focused around this:

```
for key in s3_bucket.list(Prefix="key_1/", Delimiter="/"):
        print(key.key)

 objects = client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket, Prefix="pickles/", Delimiter='/')
```

I can either include the delimiter and all it returns is the 'key_1' object or I can exclude the delimiter and I get all sub_key objects but all files as well. What can I do to just get the sub keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've actually found the answer here: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/134. The simplest way is to use the client.list_objects call as posted above and retrieve the CommonPrefixes attribute from it.